# Two different 404 documents using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site on an Apache web server. I need to configure `.htaccess` so that when you go to an address like `example.com/non-existent_page`, the `404.html` page is displayed, and when you go to an address like `example.com/ru/non-existent_page`, the page `ru/404.html` is displayed.

A similar problem is solved here: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/404-pages-on-localhost-for-multilingual-site-failing/40568/2 But for local server Hugo:

```
[[redirects]]
from = '/ru/**'
to = '/ru/404.html'
status = 404

[[redirects]]  # Default lang, should be last.
from = '/**'
to = '/404.html'
status = 404
```

Current version of my `.htaccess` is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)$ /ru/404.html [L]
```

Redirects both `example.com/ru/test` and `example.com/test` to the English version of `404.html`, i.e. to the one that lies at the root of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.html [L]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)$ /ru/404.html [L]
> ```

You just need to change the order of these rules so the more *specific* rule is first. Currently, the first rule rewrites *anything* (including URLs that start `/ru/`) that does not exist to `/404.html` and the second rule is effectively ignored.

In other words:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ru/. /ru/404.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /404.html [L]
```

(I simplified the regex a bit. The capturing subpattern is not required and there is no need to match the directory itself, since the 2nd condition would only fail anyway.)

#### Use `ErrorDocument` instead

However, the above will not serve a 404 HTTP status unless the server-side script (in a `.html` file?) sets this. Consider using an `ErrorDocument` directive instead (no need for mod_rewrite), which will instruct Apache itself to respond with the correct 404 HTTP status. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/ru/#">
    ErrorDocument 404 /ru/404.html
</If>
```

The above sets the 404 error document to `/404.html`, but overrides this when the requested URL-path starts `/ru/`. The main advantage of this approach being that Apache will set the appropriate HTTP response status.

Alternatively, have two `.htaccess` files. One in the root directory that sets `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` and one in the `/ru/` directory that sets `ErrorDocument 404 /ru/404.html`. The later will override the former.